# @KafkaListener should pull new data only when a certain conditions is met, If condition fails pulling of data should stop until the condition is met

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

The use case that I am working on is that message received from KafkaListener triggers an Async method. I want this Aysnc method to finish and only then receive a new message from kafka queue. Any ideas or suggestions regarding this implementation? Can kakfka support such kind of a scenario.

eg

```
while(asyncMethod.idle()){
@KafkaListener(String data)
public void listen(){
process(message);
asyncMethod.execute();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am confused by this question, but it sounds like you would want to make this synchronous vs. asynchronous?

Either that or you could implement a lock to basically make sure that it doesn't listen unless the lock is false and set the lock to true once it has received a message.

You may want to work on your implementation/architecture though, Kafka shouldn't be used to maintain order or block that way.